# Momentjs date validation

Tags: javascript, momentjs

When creating a moment date object using the following settings:

```
var date = moment({
    year:   2014,
    month:  2,
    day:    17,
    hour:   9,
    minute: 60
});
date.isValid(); // false

Mon Mar 17 2014 10:00:00 GMT+0100 (Romance Standard Time)
```

The output is correct but when I try to validate this date, it is incorrect. I think it's because the mintues are greater than 60. Normally this would not be a problem but i'm using [Twix](http://isaaccambron.com/twix.js/) to create ranges and due to this problem i'm getting invalid dates. Is there any way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the native `Date` constructor to deal with overflows for you :

```
var date = moment(new Date(2014,2,17,9,60));
```